# Invalid Handle with NtWow64AllocateVirtualMemory64

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Test code:

```
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI *ntalloc64t)(HANDLE, PULONG64, ULONG64, PULONG64, ULONG, ULONG);
#define NtCurrentProcess() ( (HANDLE)(PULONG64) -1 )  ;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
ULONG64 dwSize = 0x1000;

ntalloc64t ntalloc64f = (ntalloc64t)(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "NtWow64AllocateVirtualMemory64"));
PVOID pvBaseAddress;
pvBaseAddress = (PVOID)NULL;
long kk = ntalloc64f((HANDLE)GetCurrentProcess(), (PULONG64)&pvBaseAddress, 0, (PULONG64)&dwSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
}
```

I am running under WOW64. This returns 0xc0000008 which means the handle is invalid. Also does not work when passing -1 as the handle, which should indicate to WinAPI to use the current process.

Comment: Should `pvBaseAddress` be a `ULONG64` rather than a `PVOID`? Why all the casting?

Comment: because `NtCurrentProcess()` must be `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` - 8 byte -1 for x64. but you pass `0xFFFFFFFF` - what is of course invalid handle. you can not pass 8 byte -1 via this api - because high 4 bytes always will be 0. you need use `OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId())` handle only

Comment: also `pvBaseAddress` is in-out parameter. it must be initialized to 0 if you accept any allocated memory address, or must be set to concrete address, which you want allocate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we call `NtWow64AllocateVirtualMemory64` from 32-bit ntdll.dll (it exist only in wow64 ntdll.dll) the `whNtWow64AllocateVirtualMemory64` (64bit function) called inside `wow64.dll`. my reconstruction from win10 assembler code:

```
struct Wow64AllocateVirtualMemory64_Stack {
    ULONG   ProcessHandle;// !!! unsigned !!
    ULONG   BaseAddress;
    ULONG64 ZeroBits;
    ULONG   RegionSize;
    ULONG   AllocationType;
    ULONG   Protection;
};

NTSTATUS 
NTAPI 
whNtWow64AllocateVirtualMemory64(Wow64AllocateVirtualMemory64_Stack* p)
{
    return NtAllocateVirtualMemory(
        (HANDLE)(ULONG_PTR)p->ProcessHandle,
        (void**)(ULONG_PTR)p->BaseAddress, 
        p->ZeroBits, 
        (PSIZE_T)(ULONG_PTR)p->RegionSize,
        p->AllocationType, 
        p->Protection);
}
```

key point here that `HANDLE` is 32-bit size in 32 bit code and 64-bit size in 64-bit code. as result 32-bit handle value must be extended to 64-bit handle in 64bit code. but it can be **zero** or **sign** extended. of course when we extend positive 32bit value (real process handle) - no different, result will be the same. but when we extend negative value `-1` - result of zero extend will be `0xFFFFFFFF` (this is invalid handle). result of sign extend - will be `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` - correct pseudo handle to current process. windows 10 use zero extend handle:

[image]
as result we can not use -1 (`GetCurrentProcess()`) here

win8 use sign-extend handle:

[image]

however no any sense use this api for allocate memory in wow64 process. really - if we accept any memory base address, or < 4GB - we can use `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` or `VirtualAlloc[Ex]`. so this function only have sense use in case we want allocate memory at base address >= 4Gb. but this is impossible in wow64 process. - system **reserve** all memory space higher than >= 4G. typical memory map for wow64bit process (with `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` option)

[image]

so visible only 64bit ntdll.dll here, and all other memory is reserved.
without `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` option reserved range begin from `7FFF0000`. also this reserved memory can not be released - on call `NtFreeVirtualMemory` (from 64bit process) i got `STATUS_INVALID_PAGE_PROTECTION` error.

so no sense use this api for allocate inside self (and any another wow64 process). only if we want allocate memory in 64bit process and not simply allocate, but at range higher than 4GB. i even dont know for which target this can be need - why <4GB memory base, which can be allocated with usual `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` or `VirtualAlloc[Ex]` not ok. and funny that no related `NtWow64FreeVirtualMemory64` api - so impossible free alocated memory. of course possible write base-independed (and as result no import) 64bit code, embedded in 32bit process, call it via 64 call gate, this code can call functions from 64bit ntdll (and only from it) and return. this is possible, but already another story

Answer (score 3):

`NtWow64AllocateVirtualMemory64` is undocumented but you can assume that its parameters are almost the same as [`NtAllocateVirtualMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntallocatevirtualmemory) and MSDN says this about the base address parameter:

> A pointer to a variable that will receive the base address of the allocated region of pages. **If the initial value of this parameter is non-NULL, the region is allocated starting at the specified virtual address rounded down to the next host page size address boundary. If the initial value of this parameter is NULL, the operating system will determine where to allocate the region.**

You are hiding a bug with your casts; `(PULONG64)&pvBaseAddress` points to 32 zero bits from `pvBaseAddress = (PVOID)NULL` **and** 32 undefined bits from somewhere on your stack and if these bits are not all zero then you are asking for a specific base address that is probably not available!

Remove as many casts as possible and it should start working:

```
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI *ntalloc64t)(HANDLE, PULONG64, ULONG64, PULONG64, ULONG, ULONG);
ntalloc64t ntalloc64f = (ntalloc64t) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "NtWow64AllocateVirtualMemory64");
// TODO: if (!ntalloc64f) not wow64, handle error...

HANDLE hTargetProcess = OpenProcess(...);
ULONG64 base = 0, size = 0x1000;
long nts = ntalloc64f(hTargetProcess, &base, 0, &size, MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
printf("status=%d base=%I64x size=%I64x\n", nts, base, size);
```

Comment: no, with `GetCurrentProcess()` which return `-1` pseudo-handle it will be not work. you got the same error - `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE`, because `whNtWow64AllocateVirtualMemory64` api zero extend, but not sign extend handle from 32 to 64 bit. as result 32 bit `-1` extended to `0xFFFFFFFF` which is invalid handle, but not to `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. and anyway no any sense call this api for allocate memory in self( and any 32-bit process). this api only for allocate memory in 64bit process from 32bit process higher than `0x100000000`

Comment: @RbMm: The HANDLE parameter is only 32 bits in a 32-bit process (obviously) and GetCurrentProcess() worked just fine for me when I tried it. In a real scenario you would have a valid handle to another process.

Comment: no, it can not work. you mistake. are you try run code which you post ? handle is 64bit in 64bit windows. 32bit handle from wow64 bit process must be extended to 64 bit. and `whNtWow64AllocateVirtualMemory64` **zero extend** handle. as result `0xffffffff` handle used in 64 bit call. test self code under debugger

Comment: @RbMm Yes, I tested my code and it returns 0 and a valid memory address (32-bit process and GetCurrentProcess()). I did not look at the code because it is not my problem, I have a valid "handle" (given to me by kernel32) and ntdll/kernel is responsible for mapping the handle to a process pointer or whatever it needs to do to complete the operation.

Comment: under which windows version you test this ? under win10 it 100% zero-extended and can not work. may be under win7 or 8.1 another situation - need look. also note that OP also got `0xc0000008` error on -1, which say about exactly invalid handle (but not another params) error

Comment: Windows 8. Anyway, the point is moot, you should not call this on your own process and any other process handle should be valid.

Comment: yes, you correct - i just look - in win 8.1 used **sign extend** process handle - so will be work with -1. however i agree - use this api almost no sense at all. so in win10 - zero extend, in win 8.1 - sign-extend